# How to add/register and generate metrics for cassandra client program

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, codahale-metrics

In our java application we have a client program that insert bulk records into cassandra asynchronously. We are using guava Future and added callback to track success and failure for our insert operations.

Now I want to add and generate metrics to track number of record being executed through our program (method), number of success,number of failure, time taken for each insert. I would also like to get this information in hourly basis.

I am very new to cassandra and using metrics for the first time.Can you please help me to implement the above requirements. I want to know how we can register and generate metrics for client.

I have gone through https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Metrics.html - but it seems it provides statistics about cassanra server. But I want to register and generate metrics for client.

Thanks.